# Filter table by multiple pivot values

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have the following tables:

**fabrics**

```
| id| title   | code|
|-- |---------| ----|
| 1 | Fabric 1| FBR1|
| 2 | Fabric 2| FBR2|
| 3 | Fabric 3| FBR3|
| 4 | Fabric 4| FBR4|
```

**attributes**

```
| id| title      | category|
|---|------------| -----   |
| 1 | Type       | printed |
| 2 | Color      | printed |
| 3 | Composition| printed |
```

**attribute_values**

```
| id| attribute_id| text  |
|---|-----------  | ----- |
| 1 | 1           | soft  |
| 2 | 2           | yellow|
| 3 | 2           | blue  |
| 4 | 2           | black |
| 5 | 1           | dry   |
| 6 | 2           | green |
| 7 | 3           | cotton|
| 8 | 3           | wool  |
```

**fabric_attribute_value**

```
| id| attribute_value_id| fabric| attribute_id|
|---|-------------------| ------| ------------|
| 1 | 6                 | 1     | 2           |
| 2 | 7                 | 1     | 3           |
| 3 | 2                 | 2     | 2           |
| 4 | 7                 | 2     | 3           |
| 5 | 6                 | 3     | 2           |
| 6 | 8                 | 3     | 3           |
| 7 | 2                 | 4     | 2           |
| 8 | 8                 | 4     | 3           |
```

My problem is that I want to filter for example Fabrics with `Color` attribute: `yellow` OR `green` AND with the `Composition` attribute: `cotton`.

I should be getting `Fabric 1` and `Fabric 2` as results back.

How do I accomplish this query?

When there are multiple filters for the same attribute like `Color` it should be an OR inside it, but if it binds with condition with another attribute like `Composition` it should be AND. So for example in pseudo-code:

```
(Yellow(Color) OR Green(Color) AND Cotton(Composition))
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. I have taken the liberty of re-formatting your question slightly to enhance the table attributes and the actual values. I hope I got it right? Please feel free to revert if you feel I have missed something. Have you tried anything yet? If so, could you post your statement in your question by hitting the [edit] link. If not, no problem. We'll pick up from where we are.

Comment: attribute_id is redundant and should be removed from fabric_attribute_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every further filter you want to add simply increase the number in the IN Clauses

If you have a new attrubute you have to add another AND in the WHERE clause

As i said in the comment attribute_id in attribute_values is redundant

> ```
> CREATE TABLE fabric_attribute_value
>     (`id` varchar(3), `attribute_value_id` varchar(19), `fabric` varchar(6), `attribute_id` varchar(12))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO fabric_attribute_value
>     (`id`, `attribute_value_id`, `fabric`, `attribute_id`)
> VALUES
>
>     ('1', '6', '1', '2'),
>     ('2', '7', '1', '3'),
>     ('3', '2', '2', '2'),
>     ('4', '7', '2', '3'),
>     ('5', '6', '3', '2'),
>     ('6', '8', '3', '3'),
>     ('7', '2', '4', '2'),
>     ('8', '8', '4', '3')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE fabrics
>     (`id` int, `title` varchar(8), `code` varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO fabrics
>     (`id`, `title`, `code`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Fabric 1', 'FBR1'),
>     (2, 'Fabric 2', 'FBR2'),
>     (3, 'Fabric 3', 'FBR3'),
>     (4, 'Fabric 4', 'FBR4')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `title`, `code`
> FROM fabric_attribute_value av
> INNER JOIN fabrics f ON av.`fabric` = f.`id`
> WHERE (`attribute_id` = 2 AND (`attribute_value_id` IN ( 2 , 6)))
> AND `fabric` IN (SELECT `fabric` 
>                  FROM fabric_attribute_value 
>                  WHERE (`attribute_id` = 3 AND (`attribute_value_id` IN (7))))
> ```

> ```
> title    | code
> :------- | :---
> Fabric 1 | FBR1
> Fabric 2 | FBR2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `title`, `code`
> FROM fabric_attribute_value av
> INNER JOIN fabrics f ON av.`fabric` = f.`id`
> WHERE (`attribute_id` = 2 AND (`attribute_value_id` IN ( 2 , 6)))
> AND `fabric` IN (SELECT `fabric` 
>                  FROM fabric_attribute_value 
>                  WHERE (`attribute_id` = 3 AND (`attribute_value_id` IN (7, 8))))
> ```
>
> ```
> title    | code
> :------- | :---
> Fabric 1 | FBR1
> Fabric 2 | FBR2
> Fabric 3 | FBR3
> Fabric 4 | FBR4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ad3146d71d868d8ebd6addfcceb6341)*

Comment: I don't quite agree with your opinion that the `attribute_id` column is redundant. If OP would require the string `Composite` or `Color` to be part of the `Select...` statement, then it would be required. E.g. `select a1.id, a1.title, Color.id, Color.text from attributes as a1 
join attribute_values as Color 
on Color.attribute_id = a1.id
and Color.text in ('yellow','green')
and a1.title in ('Color');`. Think filling out values from an interface.

Comment: you don't get more information from that column, as you can always get it from fabric_attribute_value, if you had a lot of queries with attribute_id and want to minimize the jins maybe, but we all swear on normalization

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by joining your pivot table to itself to filter on just `Cotton` fabrics and then use a `WHERE` clause that does the additional filtering on the colors `Yellow` or `Green` like the example below. (There are other ways to accomplish this too, including if you didn't know the `id` of the attributes you wanted to filter on, but this is a simple example that achieves what you're looking for.)

```
SELECT f.title
FROM fabric_attribute_value f1
INNER JOIN f2 -- This join clause filters Fabrics that are only Cotton
    ON f1.fabric = f2.fabric
    AND f2.attribute_value_id = 7 -- Cotton
INNER JOIN fabrics f
     ON f1.fabric = f.id
WHERE attribute_value_id = 2 -- Yellow -- This where clause further filters only fabrics that are Yellow or Green
    OR attribute_value_id = 6 -- Green
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isnt returning fabrics but fabric_attribute_value. And what if i have more filters like for example (Cotton OR Wool) AND (Yellow OR Green).

Comment: @Shile Not sure if you added what you wanted to select back after I answered, but if not my apologies for missing it. I've updated my question so you get the `fabric.title` back as you requested. Your original question only asked about a specific case so my query supports that case.

Comment: @Shile but you can add on to the predicates as you further need though, for example this currently supports `(Cotton) AND (Yellow OR Green)` but you can easily add `Wool` to the `INNER JOIN f2` predicate like so: `INNER JOIN f2 ON f1.fabric = f2.fabric AND f2.attribute_value_id IN (7, 8) -- Cotton OR Wool` now supporting your case `(Cotton OR Wool) AND (Yellow OR Green)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being another fish in the pond, here is my answer to your question...

I created the tables and data based on your question:

## Table Definition & Data

### fabrics

```
create table fabrics (
id int,
title nvarchar(10),
code char(4));

insert into fabrics 
(id, title, code) values
(1, 'Fabric 1', 'FBR1'),
(2, 'Fabric 2', 'FBR2'),
(3, 'Fabric 3', 'FBR3'),
(4, 'Fabric 4', 'FBR4');
```

### attributes

```
create table attributes (
id int,
title nvarchar(15),
category nvarchar(10));

insert into attributes 
(id, title, category) values
(1, 'Type', 'printed'),
(2, 'Color', 'printed'),
(3, 'Composition', 'printed');
```

### attribute_values

```
create table attribute_values (
id int,
attribute_id int,
text nvarchar(15))

insert into attribute_values 
(id, attribute_id, text) values
(1,1,'soft'),
(2,2,'yellow'),
(3,2,'blue'),
(4,2,'black'),
(5,1,'dry'),
(6,2,'green'),
(7,3,'cotton'),
(8,3,'wool');
```

### fabric_attribute_value

```
create table fabric_attribute_value(
id int,
attribute_value_id int,
fabric int,
attribute_id int);

insert into fabric_attribute_value 
(id, attribute_value_id, fabric, attribute_id) 
values
(1,6,1,2),
(2,7,1,3),
(3,2,2,2),
(4,7,2,3),
(5,6,3,2),
(6,8,3,3),
(7,2,4,2),
(8,8,4,3);
```

## Querying the attributes for 'Color' and 'green' and 'yellow'

```
select a1.id from attributes as a1 where a1.title in('Color');
```

```
select Color.id
from attribute_values as Color 
where Color.text in ('yellow','green');
```

### Combined

```
select a1.id, a1.title, Color.id, Color.text from attributes as a1 
join attribute_values as Color 
on Color.attribute_id = a1.id
and Color.text in ('yellow','green')
and a1.title in ('Color');
```

### Resultset

| id | title | id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Color | 2 | yellow |
| 2 | Color | 6 | green |

## Querying the attributes for 'Composition'  and 'cotton'

```
select a2.id from attributes as a2 where a2.title in ('Composition');
```

```
select Composition.id
from attribute_values as Composition 
where Composition.text in ('cotton');
```

### Combined

```
select a2.id, a2.title, Composition.id, Composition.text from attributes as a2
join attribute_values as Composition
on Composition.attribute_id = a2.id
and Composition.text in ('cotton')
and a2.title in ('Composition');
```

### Resultset

| id | title | id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Composition | 7 | cotton |

## Querying the attributes for 'Type'  and '' (nothing)

```
select a3.id from attributes as a3 where a3.title in ('Type');
```

```
select Type.id
from attribute_values as Type 
where Type.text in ('');
```

### Combined

```
select a3.id, a3.title, Type.id, Type.text from attributes as a3
join attribute_values as Type
on Type.attribute_id = a3.id
and Type.text in ('')
and a3.title in ('Type')
```

### Resultset

| id | title | id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

This is basically an empty result set because the condition returns no results.

## Basic Qquery

The basic query is against the `fabric` and `fabric_attribute_value` tables based on the `id` of the fabric.

```
select distinct Fabric.title 
from fabrics as Fabric
join fabric_attribute_value as FAV -- Join fabrics with fabric_attribute_value table
    on FAV.fabric = Fabric.id
```

This has the then be joined with the conditions previously defined.

## Complex Query

```
select distinct Fabric.title 
from fabrics as Fabric
join fabric_attribute_value as FAV -- Join fabrics with fabric_attribute_value table
    on FAV.fabric = Fabric.id

and FAV.fabric in  
(
select f1.id 
from attributes as a1 
join attribute_values as Color 
    on Color.attribute_id = a1.id
    and Color.text in ('yellow','green')
    and a1.title in ('Color')
join fabric_attribute_value as fav1
    on fav1.attribute_id = Color.attribute_id
    and fav1.attribute_value_id = Color.id
join fabrics as f1
    on f1.id = fav1.fabric
) 
and FAV.fabric in
(
select f2.id 
from attributes as a2
join attribute_values as Composition
    on Composition.attribute_id = a2.id
    and Composition.text in ('cotton')
    and a2.title in ('Composition')
Join fabric_attribute_value as fav2
    on fav2.attribute_id = Composition.attribute_id
    and fav2.attribute_value_id = Composition.id
join fabrics as f2
    on f2.id = fav2.fabric
)
```

### Resultset Complex Query

| title |
| --- |
| Fabric 2 |
| Fabric 1 |

### DB Fiddle

The examples and tables can be found [here on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5aedca6f3cb06b7e9991976f85bd8c45).

## Third Condition / Complex Query

Adding a third condition results in this complex query:

```
select Fabric.title 
from fabrics as Fabric
join fabric_attribute_value as FAV -- Join fabrics with fabric_attribute_value table
    on FAV.fabric = Fabric.id

and FAV.fabric in  
(
select f1.id 
from attributes as a1 
join attribute_values as Color 
    on Color.attribute_id = a1.id
    and Color.text in ('yellow','green')
    and a1.title in ('Color')
join fabric_attribute_value as fav1
    on fav1.attribute_id = Color.attribute_id
    and fav1.attribute_value_id = Color.id
join fabrics as f1
    on f1.id = fav1.fabric
) 
and FAV.fabric in
(
select f2.id 
from attributes as a2
join attribute_values as Composition
    on Composition.attribute_id = a2.id
    and Composition.text in ('cotton')
    and a2.title in ('Composition')
Join fabric_attribute_value as fav2
    on fav2.attribute_id = Composition.attribute_id
    and fav2.attribute_value_id = Composition.id
join fabrics as f2
    on f2.id = fav2.fabric
) 
and FAV.fabric in
(
select f3.id 
from attributes as a3
join attribute_values as Type
    on Type.attribute_id = a3.id
    and Type.text in ('')
    and a3.title in ('Type')
join fabric_attribute_value as fav3
    on fav3.attribute_id = Type.attribute_id
    and fav3.attribute_value_id = Type.id
join fabrics as f3
    on f3.id = fav3.fabric
)
```

Sadly, this times out on db<>fiddle..